# Updating Nuget Package yields unlisted version

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget

So we just recently started working with Nuget and had an open source repo that we published. We took a few attempts to get the versioning right and had one version that we decided we didn't want to go with. We first released 1.0.0 and then updated with a date scheme releasing 1.0.10252017 after. We eventually decided we'd rather stick with a simpler scheme and unlisted 1.0.10252017. After this we published 1.0.1, 1.0.2, and 1.0.3 after that.

The thing that I am soo confused about is this. We are currently using this Nuget in some of our other projects and it has been awhile since the faulty version was unlisted but when I enter my Package Manager console and enter Update-Package OurNugetPackage it updates to the unlisted version! How is this possible? I can see that if I do Uninstall-Package OurNugetPackage and then Install-Package OurNugetPackage it brings in 1.0.3 is there something we are doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I found my answer. This seems to currently be a bug with the Package Manager Console in VS 2017 not filtering out unlisted packages on Update-Package commands. Uninstall-Package and then Install-Package is the current workaround.

**Open Issue on Github:** https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5069